# How to get char/text after my set keyword in richtextbox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get char/word after my keyword. In my code I've got keyword = function. When user writes in richtextbox "function a" I need to get "a" and I can't set in like function because this will be inserted by a user. My code look like this:

```
string keyword = "function";
string newString = randomString;
TextRange text = new TextRange(_richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, _richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
TextPointer current = text.Start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
while (current != null)
{
            string textInRun = current.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textInRun))
            {
                int index = textInRun.IndexOf(keyword);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    TextPointer selectionStart = current.GetPositionAtOffset(index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextPointer selectionEnd = selectionStart.GetPositionAtOffset(keyword.Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextRange selection = new TextRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                    selection.Text = newString;
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
                    _richTextBox.Selection.Select(selection.Start, selection.End);
                    _richTextBox.Focus();
                }
            }
            current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
```

Comment: You could just use string.Split and split by spaces.  Then find your keyword and grab the next item in the array.  LINQ would work here too since it is IEnumerable for readability.

Comment: `textInRun.Substring(index + keyword.Length).LTrim()`

Comment: there is an error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'LTrim' and no accessible extension method 'LTrim' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).  I highly advise you learn how to use them, as they are incredibly powerful.  Here is an example of what you could do:

```
public void ExecuteCommand (string commandText)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(commandText, @"^(\w+)\s*(.*)$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string keyword = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string parameters = match.Groups[2].Value;

        switch (keyword)
        {
            case "function":
                MyFunction(parameters);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you but how can I implement it in to my code? I'm new in c#

Comment: You could basically swap what you have with the body of the method I posted, just change `commandText` to `_richTextBox.Content` and implement `MyFunction` as appropriate.

Comment: ok but what ale the parametres for my function, I don't get it.... sorry but it is my first program in c#

Comment: Given the example you were targetting, the parameters would be 'a'.  If this is your very first program, I would suggest something easier than parsing text for learning the basics.

Comment: I know but this is for my school project, I need to find text and changed it for something new. Do you have any idea for finding words in brackets? Like ("Hello")?

Comment: The regular expression `\(\"\w+\"\)` would match that... without knowing exactly what your assignment is, I'd say you're probably over-complicating it.